# Google Chrome - Is it possible to include a SQLite db within the extension

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to include a DB file packed in with the extension when you download it.
I'm trying to include a small DB with zip codes so the extension does not have to request a look up for the proper zip code.

possible at all?

Comment: What about coding your database as a simple JavaScript array/object?

Comment: I was thinking about making it a JSON or an array, I wanted to try and see if I could keep the functions pretty much the same for access the packed DB and the HTML5 DB. There are quite a lot of zip-codes. We are suffering from the lack of a frontend person with a little bit of JS knowledge for our startup. I was trying to keep things as simple as possible. If I could pack it in a SQLite file and ship it, it would be easier to manage packing up the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what I would do in a Chrome Extension, is packaging it up with a "zip_codes.json" file. Then when your extension loads, use XHR to read that file. For example, the below snippet is to asynchronously (you can use synchronous too if you want) get the zip codes stored in your extension.

```
var zipcodes = {};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('zip_codes.json'), false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  zip_codes = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(zip_codes);
}
```

I would believe this approach would be easier to manage than adding your own localStorage cache for the files, because once you ship it, you can always update that file.

So if your zip_codes.json file has the following:

```
{
  33445: 'Some zip'
}
```

You can just access that zip code using the following approach:

```
console.log(zip_codes[33445]);
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to have to work on some backend tools to pull data out of our DBs and convert it into something more transferable. I was hoping to skip the step of converting data. There a few other projects we are working on that could use that. Thank you for the well formed answer. ---Time for more tools!

Comment: It doesn't have to be JSON, it could be XML as well. Instead of doing JSON.parse(xhr.responseText), if it were XML, you could do "var dom = xhr.responseXml)", and use the normal DOM manipulations like .getAttribute, .getElementsByName, etc. It could even be any structure your want. The whole point is to store it in your extension, and XHR to read it. I like JSON better since it is easier on the developer since they will have access to one huge JSON object. Make sure it is hosted in the background page.